# Booting ubuntu 22.04 cloud image in rockylinux 9.2 failed

Tags: 22.04, kvm-virtualization

I have downloaded ubuntu 22.04 cloud image from below link and converted the same to qcow2 to be used in cockpit in Rockylinux. I have resized the disk size to 100GB as shown in below picture.

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img

Then I have used "import vm" option to start the VM and it fails saying not a bootable disk as shown below. On the same setup I do have ubuntu 22.04 server vm running successfully without any issue installed from dvd rom.

[image]

When I try the same without converting the image from .img to .qcow2 I am seeing a different error as shown below

[image]